# Can we say anything about the existence of $\lim(a_n-a_{n-1})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Given a positive sequence $a_n$ satisfying the following inequality:
$$a_{n+m} \le a_n+a_m$$
I was wondering whether we can say anything about the convergence of $b_n:=a_n-a_{n-1}$

From the abovementioned inequality, one can obtain the following relation:
$$a_n-a_{n-1} \le a_1$$
And, therefore, $b_n$ is upper-bounded with $a_1$. Now if one could show that $b_n$ is an increasing sequence, then we'd be done!

I couldn't show this, though. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The sequence is a sub-additive sequence it has some properties may be useful to you. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162848/regarding-sub-additive-sequences-and-feketes-lemma,

Comment: @EDX thanks for the reference! It will definitely be helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple counterexample is
$$
 (a_n)_{n \ge 0} = 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, \ldots
$$
which is strictly positive and subadditive:
$$
 a_{n+m} \le 2 = 1 + 1 \le a_n + a_m \, .
$$
(Actually the sequence is *strictly* subadditive since equality cannot hold simultaneously in both estimates.)

Comment: Indeed a more simple example. I recommend changing the accepted answer to this one.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions given do not imply that the sequence $(b_n)$ is increasing nor converging.

Consider the sequence $(a_n)$ where $a_n = 1+1/n$ for $n$ odd, $a_n = 1/2$ for $n$ divisible by $2$ but not $4$, and $a_n = 1/4$ for $n$ divisible by $4$. Now $(b_n)$ is not increasing, and does not converge.